# USB Webcam stopped working on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, usb, camera

I've always been using a PS3 Eye Webcam on my Laptop with Debian 9.
I did not do anything that I could bring in relation with the camera not working.
Now there is no /dev/video0 device or anything close.

Also, the integrated camera doesn't work or show up either.

Didn't do any noticable changes.
If you need any more information let me know.

How can I fix this?

Edit:

- lsusb detects the camera.

dmesg: (after detecting the camera)

```
usb 1-2.3: current rate 1464 is different from the runtime rate 16000
usb 1-2.3 3:1: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 3)
```

(shows this three times with different values)

Have tried the camera on a different computer, works flawlessly.
Tried other cameras on this computer, didn't work, same Problem.
Tried booting into another kernel, didn't work, same problem.

Comment: did you do basic troubleshooting before you posted? ... also, you did not ask a question, you only described your observations

Comment: I did. see the edits

Comment: basic troubleshooting includes trying the canera on another computer

Comment: Okay, I just updated the Kernel and it somehow works again.